# What's the best record datatype to store a file-path in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, filepath

Which data type in SQLite is best suited to storing a file path?

Comment: For example, varchar(N). In sqlite3 varchar datatype doesn't exist, does it? I suppose I have to use the text datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlite3 supports varchar(n), but doesn't enforce the 'n'.

```
sqlite> create table test (fullpath varchar(10) primary key);
sqlite> insert into test values ('/usr/local/bin/sqlite3');
sqlite> select * from test;
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

This is a [frequently asked question](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9).